# PHP Conditional Statement skips elseif

Tags: php, regex, if-statement, checkbox, conditional-statements

I have an array of checkboxes coded as:

```
<form action="CascadeFunction.php" method="post" name="cascader" id="cascader">
    <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="EMEA" /><label for="EMEA">EMEA</label><br />
    <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="NAM" /><label for="NAM">NAM</label><br />
    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="POST &amp; CASCADE" />
</form>
```

The following code checks which of those checkboxes are checked. Then by checking the imploded checkbox value, it adds the corresponding email addresses to the `$toList` array.

```
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$checkboximploded = implode($checkbox);
$toList = array(
    'firstemail@email.com' => 'First Email',
    'secondemail@email.com' => 'Second Email',
);

if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    foreach ($checkbox as $value) {

            if (preg_match('/EMEA/',$checkboximploded)) {
                $toList["thirdemail@email.com"] = "Third Email";
                $toList["fourthemail@email.com"] = "Fourth Email";
            }
           elseif (preg_match('/NAM/',$checkboximploded)) {
                $toList["fifthemail@email.com"] = "Fifth Email";
                $toList["sixthemail@email.com"] = "Sixth Email";
        }   
}   
            foreach($toList as $email => $name) {
                $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
            }
```

The code works perfectly only if one of the checkboxes is checked. The problem is, if both are checked, it only adds the email addresses found on the 1st `if` statement and never continues to the `elseif` statement. What I want to happen is if all 2 checkboxes are checked, it should add all 4 email addresses to the existing `$toList`array.

I already spent 8 hours solving the issue but can't find the correct solution. Kindly advise why it seems to be skipping the `elseif` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

- Change your `elseif` to an `if` (and get rid of the loop), or
- Change your `preg_match` to check against `$value`

Here's why. If both check boxes are ticked, then `$_POST['checkbox']` is `array ('EMEA', 'NAM')` and thus `$checkboximploded` is `"EMEANAM"`, which matches the regular expression of the `if` as well as the `elseif`. But since `if` comes first, `if` wins, regardless of the fact that you're iterating over `$checkbox.`

Also, `preg_match` may be overkill: `strpos` would suffice in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Change the elseif to a simple IF
From this...

```
    elseif (preg_match('/NAM/',$checkboximploded)) {
```

To this...

```
    if (preg_match('/NAM/',$checkboximploded)) {
```

Comment: What a very simple solution. I never knew that you can use another if after you already used it. I thought "if" should always be followed either by elseif or else. Thanks! I should have asked this earlier instead of spending hours. LOL!

Answer (score 1):

Because your else if is exactly that: an else if (meaning: only check the second condition if the first is not met).

If you would make that a normal if (drop the else) you would tell the program to check for both conditions *independent* from each other, which is what you want based on your description.